Invalid runtime for JavaSE-19: The path (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19) does not point to a JDK
My springboot project that worked perfectly fine 2 months ago doesnt run now. Its showing this error
Invalid runtime for JavaSE-19: The path (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19) does not point to a JDK.
My settings.json file-
{
    "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true,
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark - C++",
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.organizeImports": "explicit"
    },
    "editor.linkedEditing": true,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "editor.rulers": [
        {
            "column": 80,
            "color": "#00FF0010"
        },
        {
            "column": 100,
            "color": "#BDB76B15"
        },
        {
            "column": 120,
            "color": "#FA807219"
        }
    ],
    "editor.unicodeHighlight.includeComments": true,
    "emmet.variables": {
        "lang": "en"
    },
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "[Default Dark Modern]": {
            "tab.activeBorderTop": "#00FF00",
            "tab.unfocusedActiveBorderTop": "#00FF0088",
            "textCodeBlock.background": "#00000055"
        },
        "editor.wordHighlightStrongBorder": "#FF6347",
        "editor.wordHighlightBorder": "#FFD700",
        "editor.selectionHighlightBorder": "#A9A9A9"
    },
    "workbench.editor.revealIfOpen": true,
    "workbench.tree.indent": 20,
    "files.eol": "\n",
    "[bat]": {
        "files.eol": "\r\n"
    },
    "terminal.integrated.enablePersistentSessions": false,
    "terminal.integrated.tabs.hideCondition": "never",
    "java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "automatic",
    "java.debug.settings.hotCodeReplace": "auto",
    "java.sources.organizeImports.staticStarThreshold": 1,
    "cSpell.diagnosticLevel": "Hint",
    "trailing-spaces.includeEmptyLines": false,
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [

        {
            "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
            "path": "C:\\Users\\tejas\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\\java\\8"
        },
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-11",
            "path": "C:\\Users\\tejas\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\\java\\11"
        },
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-17",
            "path": "C:\\Users\\tejas\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\\java\\17",
            "default": true
        },
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-19",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-19",
            //"default": true //new
        },
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-21",
            "path": "C:\\Users\\tejas\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\\java\\21"
        },
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-22",
            "path": "C:\\Users\\tejas\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\\java\\latest"
        }
    ],
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "JavaSE-21 LTS",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "JavaSE-1.8 LTS": {
            "overrideName": true,
            "env": {
                "PATH": "C:\\Users\\tejas\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\\java\\8\\bin;${env:PATH}",
                "JAVA_HOME": "C:\\Users\\tejas\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\\java\\8"
            },
            "path": "cmd"
        },
        "JavaSE-11 LTS": {
            "overrideName": true,
            "env": {
                "PATH": "C:\\Users\\tejas\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\\java\\11\\bin;${env:PATH}",
                "JAVA_HOME": "C:\\Users\\tejas\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\\java\\11"
            },
            "path": "cmd"
        },
        "JavaSE-17 LTS": {
            "overrideName": true,
            "env": {
                "PATH": "C:\\Users\\tejas\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\\java\\17\\bin;${env:PATH}",
                "JAVA_HOME": "C:\\Users\\tejas\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\\java\\17"
            },
            "path": "cmd"
        },
        "JavaSE-19": {
            "overrideName": true,
            "env": {
                "PATH": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-19\\bin;${env:PATH}",
                "JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS": "-Dstdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dstderr.encoding=UTF-8",
                "JAVA_HOME": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-19"
            },
            "path": "cmd",
            "args": [
                "/k",
                "chcp",
                "65001"
            ]
        },
        "JavaSE-21 LTS": {
            "overrideName": true,
            "env": {
                "PATH": "C:\\Users\\tejas\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\\java\\21\\bin;${env:PATH}",
                "JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS": "-Dstdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dstderr.encoding=UTF-8",
                "JAVA_HOME": "C:\\Users\\tejas\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\\java\\21"
            },
            "path": "cmd",
            "args": [
                "/k",
                "chcp",
                "65001"
            ]
        },
        "JavaSE-22": {
            "overrideName": true,
            "env": {
                "PATH": "C:\\Users\\tejas\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\\java\\latest\\bin;${env:PATH}",
                "JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS": "-Dstdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dstderr.encoding=UTF-8",
                "JAVA_HOME": "C:\\Users\\tejas\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\\java\\latest"
            },
            "path": "cmd",
            "args": [
                "/k",
                "chcp",
                "65001"
            ]
        }
    },
    "java.import.gradle.home": "C:\\Users\\tejas\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\\gradle\\latest",
    "java.import.gradle.java.home": "C:\\Users\\tejas\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\\java\\21",
    "maven.terminal.customEnv": [
        {
            "environmentVariable": "JAVA_HOME",
            "value": "c:\\Users\\tejas\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\\java\\17"
        }
    ],
    "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
        "PATH": "c:\\Users\\tejas\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\\java\\17\\bin;${env:PATH}",
        "JAVA_HOME": "c:\\Users\\tejas\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\\java\\17"
    },
    "cmake.showOptionsMovedNotification": false,
    "trailing-spaces.backgroundColor": "rgba(255,0,0,0.1)",
    "java.configuration.detectJdksAtStart": false,
    "terminal.integrated.automationProfile.windows": {
        "path": "cmd"
    },
    "java.test.config": {
        "vmArgs": [
            "-Dstdout.encoding=UTF-8",
            "-Dstderr.encoding=UTF-8"
        ]
    },
    "git.openRepositoryInParentFolders": "never",
    "java.dependency.packagePresentation": "hierarchical",
    "maven.executable.path": "C:\\Users\\tejas\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\\maven\\latest\\bin\\mvn",
    "java.compile.nullAnalysis.mode": "automatic"
}

the pom.xml that im using -
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>enotes</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>enotes</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

the environment variables related to java ive set are
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre-1.8\bin
How do I fix this and why did this happen?

Quite a big omission: you don't mention whether there is JDK19 installed at that path, and whether you've tested it say with java -version

Execute the "Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace" command from the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P). LTS versions of the JDK are located in C:\\Users\\tejas\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\pleiades.java-extension-pack-jdk\\java.

Solution figured-
Use java 17 to build the app and didnt have java 17 jdk installed on my pc. I set that up and also make sure to run the code from root directory itself and not within a subfile

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
